# Why cannot transfer the documentclass[article] to documentclass[letter]?

Tags: document-classes

I'm a freshman to use latex. I don't know why cannot transfer the documentclass[article] to documentclass[letter]?

Here is the error information:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [10pt].

(./未命名-1.aux) (D:/Latex/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [0{C:/Users/admin/AppDa
ta/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]

! LaTeX Error: Environment abstract undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 \begin{abstract}
                   
?
```

The code like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{letter}
%\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
%\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\title{The Influence of Advanced Driver-assistance Systems
and the Future with Autonomous Vehicle}
\author{Minglang Tuo}
\date{Oct 2020}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}


There are two relative technology descibed in the essay. One has a profound effect on my life and another technology that I believe will be the next big thing in computer science. While driving system technology such as \emph{advanced driver-assistance systems} are essential now, in the future the system will generate automatic route and operate the automobiles to drive these paths. The technology of \emph{autonomous vehicle} will have significant infulence.  





\end{abstract}

\section{Advanced Driver-assistance Systems}



There are several top four computer realted technologies that infulenced in the social. I would probably choose the following.
\begin{enumerate}
 \item E-commerce

  \item Global Positioning(GPS)

  \item NLP

    \item Computer Vision
\end{enumerate}
Advanced driver-assistance systems is a technology that had a profound effect on my life, which assists drivers in driving and parking functions by electronic systems and software.ADAS increase car and road safety by the safe human-machine interface. Based on the sensors and cameras, the ADAS can detect nearby obstacles or driver errors. For example, antilock brake system are configured to most of vehicles. 

It's an early ADAS technology in the vehicle area. When the traffic accidents or other emergency situations happen, it helps car automatically control the power of brake to ensure the wheel not locked and guarantee the adhesion between wheels and surface in maximum value. I think ADAS can helps us drive cars more safely and easily.


\section{Autonomous Vehicle}




Autonomous vehicle technology \emph{(vechicle that is capable of sensing its environment and moving safely with little or no human input)} is a new technology that has likely to be very necessary in the future. Self-driving cars combine a variety of sensors to perceive their surroundings, such as radar, sonar, GPS and inertial measurement units. 

Also, it uses the knowledge of deep learing and computer vison to process lots of data. The appropriate navigation paths, obstacles and relevent signage will be identify by the algorithms.It's important for users because an unmanned vehicle fleet composed of multiple autonomous vehicles can effectively reduce traffic pressure and thus improve transportation efficiency of the transportation system. 
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
Application & Example(s) \\
\hline
Delivering food & Autonomous delivery vehicles deliver foods and drinks \\
\hline
Military & Deploy relevant military facilities \\
\hline
Space  & Deploy ships to search for living planets \\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

However, I can transfer to the report(\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{report}), and there is no error.
Please help me! Thanks

Comment: A `letter` does not know commands such as abstract. Remove the abstract and the title and maybe even the sections and you are good to go. 
Did you mean to get a letter size to your paper or do you want to write a letter?

Comment: `\documentclass[twocolumns,10pt,letterpaper]{article}` in case you were looking for the paper format.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thanks, the problem has been resolved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get your paper in letter size, please do `\documentclass[twocolumns,10pt,letterpaper]{article}`

If you want to write a letter, you should avoid environments such as `abstract` as those are not defined for letters.